# cannot find a module from a different database in marklogic

Tags: javascript, module, marklogic, marklogic-9

OK i have a MarkLogic 9.0.2 database in which I have two applications deployed. Lets say A and B. Now I want to run some code inside B from A, we can do this with the `xdmp.eval()` but the code I want to run needs to find a module deployed in the modules database of B.

I cannot seem to get this working.

Code run inside database B works :

```
declareUpdate();
var prj = require('/root/lib/project-lib.xqy');
prj.createProject('giraffe', 'A project about giraffes');
```

finds and runs the createProject function in the module library...

Now from database A I try to run this by an `xdmp.eval()` like so:

```
declareUpdate();

var options = { "isolation" : "different-transaction", 
                "database" : xdmp.database("data-hub-FINAL"),
                "modules" : xdmp.database("data-hub-MODULES")
              }

xdmp.eval("declareUpdate();var prj = require('/root/lib/project-lib.xqy');prj.createProject('fromcluey giraffe', 'A project about giraffes from cluey');"
  , options);
```

But gives me:

> [javascript] XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: declareUpdate();var prj = require('/root/lib/project-lib.xqy');prj.createProject('fromcluey giraffe', 'A project about giraffes from cluey'); -- Module /root/lib/project-lib.xqy not found

Can someone tell me how I am supposed to find the `project-lib.xqy` module from inside A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document permissions was the first thing I was thinking of, which also applies to modules, schemas, triggers etc, not just to documents. Privileges second. Modules root can definitely be important as well.

However, there is a simple typo in the above `xdmp.eval` that is the biggest culprit here: the function takes 3 arguments, not 2. And `options` is the 3rd, not the second.

It should be: `xdmp:eval("...", null, options)`.

HTH!

Comment: yes it was as simple as this, would be nice if the interpreter would warn about such trivial mistake.

Comment: The issue is that both 2nd and 3rd arguments are hash tables, so it just thinks options are variables that need to be passed in..